# Heroku Toolbelt Issues

Tags: heroku, download, installation, fault

having just downloaded the tool belt (OS x 10.7) and installed it to be used "by all users of this computer", I've been trying to find/open it but there is no sign of it ANYwhere on my computer... Random but yeah, please advise. Thanks, Patrick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be at `/usr/local/heroku`. Make sure `/usr/local/heroku/bin` is on your `$PATH`.